# Type-only imports break Angular's Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript3.8, type-only-import-export

Angular DI system does not respect TypeScript 3.8 type-only imports.

```js
import type { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

...

@Component({
    templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef    // ERROR: Consider changing the type-only import to a regular import, or use the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token
  ) {}
}
```

Is there any possibility how to use type-only imports in Angular?

Comment: Can you remove the `readonly` keyword from your ChangeDetectorRef?

Comment: What is your actual goal here? A type is not ‘just’ injectable using DI. If you just need the type, you don’t actually have to DI it in the constructor, you can just import and use.

Comment: @MikeOne No. In the constructor we provide type references for DI subsystem. They're not used as values (e.g. for instantiation). It should work with types, actually.
Instead, it throws DI error.
The goal is to use type-only imports, obviously.

Comment: No solution to this extremely common issue?  Work around is to actually decorate each injected constructor parameter with `@Inject(TypeHere)` but that is very verbose.